# Using another classes function in c#

Tags: c#, function, methods, dice

im trying to be able to call the function from the dieclass and use the roll number in the matchplay class... is this possible?

```
public class DieClass
{
    public void DiceRoll(int min, int max)
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        int roll1 = random.Next(0, 6);
        int roll2 = random.Next(0, 6);
        int roll3 = random.Next(0, 6);
    }
}

public class MatchPlay
{
    public void Match()
    {
        DieClass.DiceRoll();

        Console.WriteLine("Starting Match Play...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Round One");
        Console.WriteLine("Your first dice is [0]", roll1);
        Console.WriteLine("Your second dice is [0]", roll2);
        Console.WriteLine("Your third dice is [0]", roll3);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: A class is not an object - more like a blueprint.  You need to *instantiate* and object of type DieClass to use it as an object.  You also need to read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You need to learn C# basics first. Either make DiceRoll static method or instantiate the DieClass. Also pass the min, max parameters. You need to return the value in order to print them.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things that need fixin':

- Your `DiceRoll` method is an instance method, so you'd need to create an instance of the `DiceClass` class in order to use it.
- The `roll1`, `roll2`, and `roll3` variables are local to the method, so you won't be able to use them once the method completes. Instead, you might make them public properties of the class.
- You don't need to instantiate a new `Random` every time the method is called (in fact this can lead to problems because `Random` is seeded with a value based on the system clock, so if your method is called very rapidly, it will produce the same numbers over and over). You can just make it static and instantiate it once.
- Since you're taking in `min` and `max` arguments to the `Roll` method, shouldn't we use them? You currently have `0` and `6` hard-coded.
- To use a format string, you need to use the curley braces (`{}`) instead of square brackets (`[]`).
- Finally, from a naming convention point of view, you don't need the word `Class` as part of your class name, and you don't need `Dice` as part of the method name. This will simplify the amount of typing, and will still be very understandable.

What you might consider doing is creating a class that represents a single `Die` object, and give it a `Roll()` method and a `Value` property. Then the user can create as many as they like and keep them in a List:

```
public class Die
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    // Make this static and instantiate it only once to avoid re-seeding issues
    private static readonly Random rnd = new Random();

    public Die()
    {
        Value = 1;
    }

    public void Roll()
    {
        // This method uses values 1-6 as a standard die
        Roll(1, 6);
    }

    public void Roll(int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        Value = rnd.Next(minValue, maxValue + 1);
    }
}
```

Now, you can use the `Die` class as follows:

```
public class MatchPlay
{
    public void Match()
    {
        // Add three Die objects to our list of dice
        List<Die> dice = new List<Die>
        {
            new Die(), new Die(), new Die()
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Starting Match Play...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Round One");

        // Roll all dice
        dice.ForEach(d => d.Roll());

        Console.WriteLine("Your first dice is {0}", dice[0].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Your second dice is {0}", dice[1].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Your third dice is {0}", dice[2].Value);
    }
}
```

Finally, we can kick off a match in our `Main` method:

```
private static void Main()
{
    MatchPlay game = new MatchPlay();
    game.Match();

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Nice work. I would make Roll return the value too, but that a minor point

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea. Then you could both `Roll` and output the `Value` at once... `Console.WriteLine("After rolling the die, the value is: {0}", dice[0].Roll());`

Answer (score 2):

Either you need to make `DiceRoll` a `static` method, or create an instance of `DieClass` and call your method through that.

For example, you may declare your method as

```
public static void DiceRoll(int min, int max)
```

Or you can instantiate an object like:

```
DieClass dice = new DieClass();

dice.DiceRoll(0, 6);
```

That being said, you have other problems with your `DieClass` class, the most obvious of which is you need a means of communicating the result back to the caller. The easiest approach would be to have `DiceRoll()` generate a single result and return that. Also, you've hardcoded `0` and `6` as your params to `random.Next()` despite the method expecting a pair of parameters `min` and `max`.